# How to find if two binary trees are identical in terms of content?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I see several posts around how to determine if two trees are same in terms of its structure but have not found any answer on how to find if two trees are same in terms of content.

Say, tree node is defined as follows.

```
TreeNode {
    string data;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right
};
```

Now I have two binary tree and need to find out if two trees are same in terms of content. These two may not be structurally identical nor we cannot assume that the data string is identical in words.

For instance, we might have following two trees. These two trees can be treated as identical in terms of content when we do inorder walk. To be clear, when we concatenate all the node strings from these two trees, they are same. i.e. abcdedfg

```
 (abc)
 |   \
 (d) (efg)

 (a)
 |  \
 (b) (cdefg)
```

I know that we can do inorder walk to collect all the string of both trees and we can compare the resulting two strings but I want to know if there is more efficient way of comparing two trees by either somehow walking the two trees in parallel or creating an iterator. None of these seemed very obvious to me so wanted to get some feedback and maybe some code snippet to get better ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would do the in order walk as you said, but compare until you find 2 different elements. This has min(n,m) time complexity in the worst case so the fastest possible algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just updated my question. It would be helpful if you can provide some code samples. ;-)

Comment: Yep, see my answer for full code in python, it uses generator to make it faster.

Comment: Sorry are you saying the two trees in the example equal or not?

Comment: I feel like you are abusing the binary tree data structure a bit. What do you gain from having it structured like that?

Comment: Can one or both of the trees be altered, or can additional space be used?

Comment: In the example given, they should be treated as identical.

Comment: How is it that you end up with this particular structure, specifically, with >1 character in each node? What determines whether there is 2 3 4 5 .. characters in a given node? I would suggest, if you normalize the structure - one character per node your going to land on a more efficient solution. But again, its not clear what the context is.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to write the generator that yields letters from sorted elements one by one. This is faster than generating all letters at once since for example it may be detected that the trees are different from first letter and in this case it will not compare remaining letters. In Python this would be:

```
def iter_bin_tree_letters(tree):
    if tree.left:
        for letter in iter_bin_tree_letters(tree.left)
            yield letter
    # RETURN ITERATOR OVER LETTERS  <----------
    for letter in tree.data:
        yield letter
    if tree.right:
        for letter in iter_bin_tree_letters(tree.right)
            yield letter
```

Now simply compare results from both generators until you find 2 different elements or run out of elements:

```
def are_equal_bin_trees(tree1, tree2):
    t1 = iter_bin_tree_letters(tree1)
    t2 = iter_bin_tree_letters(tree2)
    t1_empty = False
    while True:
        try:
            e1 = t1.next()
        except:
            t1_empty = True
        try:
            e2 = t2.next()
        except:
           if not t1_empty:
               return False
           return True
        if e1!=e2:
             return False
```

This is the fastest possible algorithm, it has time complexity of min(n,m) in the worst case.

Comment: Thank you and I don't know python. Well, it looks like python to me ;-) . Quick question.  does your code handle my sample case? The first node from the first tree returns 'abc' while the first node from the second tree returns just 'a'. When we concatenate, two strings become identical but each node string may be different.

Comment: It compares node by node. I don't concatenate anything. In your sample case it compares first b and d and detects they are different so it returns False. If they were the same it would go on and compare 'a' to 'abc' and so on.

Comment: Thanks Piotr for clarification. Perhaps it was not clear but wanted to find ways to compare the entire content not just node by node comparison.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not read that properly. Hold on a second I will modify it and add comments, the idea is the same.

Comment: Okay, I modified the code and it works now in your case and is as fast as possible :)  You should be able to understand this code but in case of any questions please ask

Comment: I just realised its simpler to just return the iterator over the letters instead of iterator over the nodes

Comment: Because I don't know python, let me ask some naive question. From the way I see, it seems that it's using recursion. If that's the case and say we just returned the element/string from left child node in my example, how does this iter_bin_tree_elems() go up to parent node when we call that method again? Unless we remember our recursive stack information, it seems difficult to go up from where we left off... Sorry if that's obvious to you in python.

Comment: Yes Python remembers whole stack here. It returns letters from left to right. What language do you know? So I maybe be able to explain in this language.

Comment: Cool. It's good to know that python takes care of it. I am using C++ and it seems that I will have to use iterative approach with explicit stack to remember where I left off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through both trees using DFS (depth first search) comparing character by character. This would also be combined with a two-finger algorithm where you would iterate through the nodes of each tree at different speeds depending on what element you are up to.

As from your example. Tree 1 and Tree, where Node X-Y is row X, element Y. E.g. Tree 1 Node 2-2 is "efg":

```
Tree 1
(abc)
 |   \
 (d) (efg)

Tree 2
 (a)
 |  \
 (b) (cdefg)
```

The algorithm would walk through the nodes of each tree in turn, comparing character by character.

1. Start from **Tree 1 Node 1-1**
2. Start from **Tree 2 Node 1-1**
3. Compare a1 with a2
4. Advance to **Tree 2 Node 2-1**
5. Compare b1 with b2
6. Advance to **Tree 2 Node 2-2**
7. Compare c1 with c2
8. Advance to **Tree 1 Node 2-1**
9. Compare d1 with d2
10. Advance to **Tree 1 Node 2-2**
11. Compare e1 with e2
12. Compare f1 with f2
13. Compare g1 with g2
14. Return **Identical!**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right, that's what I want to accomplish but could not find any easy way to write the code. Perhaps Piotr's answer does it but it's not obvious to me whether it's doing it so asked for clarification.

Comment: Piotr's answer is quite good and is in-line with my algorithm. He's using a Python iterator to allow you to iterate over the letters while completely hiding the underlying tree structure. Then the function that compares the two trees just loops through the two iterators and ensures they are the same. What language would you prefer the answer in?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to enumerate all the nodes in both trees to see whether or not they have different content.

It isn't possible to know if a node is or is not in a tree unless you traverse all the nodes in the tree. For example

```
 a      a
b c    c d
```

You see `ab` and `ac` in two passes. You don't know if tree 1 contains `c` or tree 2 contains `b` unless you traverse the entirety of both trees.

While you iterate through, you can put each of the nodes in a separate priority queue, and pop values off the top of the queues until you reach the values you popped off are not equal. This makes your average case much faster than using a normal queue, for the heuristic overhead of an `log(n)` insertion for each node in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

hash the two data structures or compare them using a naive o(n) algorithm. every data structure can be represented as a stream of bytes. yes, using pointers is a problem in this case and should be avoided.

I'm assuming the trees are generated by the same algorithm so there cannot be two different trees which have the same content.

Answer (score 0):

We can first store the traversal of both trees in array - cost O(n)
Now we traverse both arrays and do XOR of all elements , if XOR
is zero then they are identical else not  identical - cost O(n)
So we can do in O (n).